# query the two table for draw in one

Tags: mysql, sql

Here are my tables in mysql:

```
        ----------------1-------------------------  
        +---------------------------+----------+
        | email                     | attempts |
        +---------------------------+----------+
        | email1@gmail.com          |       70 |
        | email2@me.com             |        1 |
        | email3@hotmail.com        |        1 |
        | email4@gmail.com          |      115 |
        +---------------------------+----------+
       ---------------2------------------------
        +----------+---------------------------+
        | accesses | email                     |
        +----------+---------------------------+
        |       24 | email1@gmail.com          |
        |        0 | email2@me.com             |
        |        0 | email3@hotmail.com        |
        |       90 | email4@gmail.com          |
        +----------+---------------------------+
```

query the two table for draw in one

```
Email   Accesses    Attempts
email1    24            70
email2     0             1
email3     0             1
email4    90           115
```

it is the sql:

1. first -> `select accesses, email from user;`
2. second -> `select email,count(*) as intentos from userstats where intento =1 group by email;`

how do I do this?
I need a query to do draw. thank's in advance..

Comment: Which is the `userstats` table?

Comment: You should think about normalising your schema. If each email address has one entry in each table then you might want to consider combining the two tables into one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT table1.email as Email, 
    table2.accesses as Acesses, 
    table1.attempts as Attempts
from table1 
INNER JOIN table2 
on table1.email = table2.email
```

Comment: Note: removed erroneous comma

Comment: thanks. my query select  userstats.email as email, count(intento) as intentos, user.accesses as logeos from userstats inner join user on user.email = userstats.email group by Email;

Answer (score 0):

You can use INNER JOIN to do this

```
SELECT 
    t1.email, t1.accesses , t2.attempts 
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN 
    table2 t2 ON
        t2.email = t1.email;
```